# Unable to get text from HTML DOM using Symfony DomCrawler

Tags: php, symfony, dom, domcrawler

I am crawling an HTML using symfony `DomCrawler`.
I am providing the snippet of HTML that I need to fetch:

```
<p class="accounts">
  <b>Account:</b>
  <span class="no-wrap">1234567</span>
  <br>
  <b>Type</b>
  987654
</p>
```

Now I need **987654** text, but I am unsuccessful in doing that.
Here is what I have tried:

```
$dom->filterXPath('//p[@class="accounts"]')->children()->eq(4)->text();
$dom->filterXPath('//p[@class="accounts"]')->children()->eq(4)->html();
$dom->filterXPath('//p[@class="accounts"]')->children()->text();
```

I am able to get **1234567** as it is under a **tag**, here it is what I did:

```
$dom->filterXPath('//p[@class="accounts"]')->children()->eq(1);
```